# Managing global objects with side effects when reloading a module in Python

Tags: python, module, side-effects

I am looking for a way to correctly manage module level global variables that use some operating system resource (like a file or a thread).

The problem is that when the module is reloaded, my resource must be properly disposed (e.g. the file closed or the thread terminated) before creating the new one.

So I need a better pattern to manage those singleton objects.

Comment: How to do you reload the module ? is pickling involved ?

Comment: It is used in django, so whatever mechanism it uses for hot-reloading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been reading the docs on module reload and this is quite interesting:

> When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s
>   global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override
>   the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. If the new
>   version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old
>   version, the old definition remains. This feature can be used to the
>   module’s advantage if it maintains a global table or cache of objects
>   — with a try statement it can test for the table’s presence and skip
>   its initialization if desired:

```
try:
    cache
except NameError:
    cache = {}
```

So I could just check if the objects already exist, and dispose them before creating the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to monkeypatch or fork django to hook into [django dev server reloading feature](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py) and do the proper thing to manage file closing etc...

**But**  since you develop a django application, if you mean to use a proper server to serve your app in the future you should consider managing your global variables and think about [semaphores](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) and [all that jazz](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).

**But** before going this route and implement all this difficult code prone to error and hair loss. You should consider other solution like [nosql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql) databases ([redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis), [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), [neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4j), [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop)...) and background process managers like [celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/celery) and [gearman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gearman). If all of this don't feet your use-case(s) and you can't avoid to create and manage files yourself and global variables then consider the [client/server](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=client%20server%20pattern) pattern where clients are webserver threads unless you want to mess with [NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/NFS).